# How can I combine subplots (Partial Dependent plot) in Python?

Tags: python

How can I combine subplots of the Partial Dependent plot in Python?

The Partial Dependent plot was made by using sklearn library (as attached in the picture below).

I saw the plot type is "subplot" (matplot lib), But I cannot find a way to combine the dependent plots.

And those plots were the results of the random forest model.

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2kQQ.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.